# Fetching Private Messages of users on Facebook using RestFB

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I am new to using Java APIs and am very confused about using RestFB to fetch user private messages from Facebook.

What i have figured till now..

```
 Connection<Message> cnv = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/inbox", Message.class);
    //System.out.println(cnv.getData().get(1).getId());
    for(Message msg:cnv.getData()){
         System.out.println(msg.getMessage());
    }
```

Here the ID of one particular conversation is being fetched properly but nothing else. All other getter methods return null.

I am unable to understand if Message.class is the correctly mapped POJO to message threads, or Conversation.class .

I would be grateful if someone immediately answered this question as i am stuck here and need quick relief.

1. What is the correct way to go about this, please attach a code
   sample. I want to fetch all private messages of a user.  2)
2. I read somewhere FB allows only 25 items or something? what is this? Does
   it concern me?
3. I need to fill my own domain POJOs, so i need not only
     a. All the chat messages
     b. Based on thread ID
     c. Based on after a certain received time .

Comment: someone please reply... emergency ... need help

Comment: If my comment resolved your issue please mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
// Conversation class is needed to retrieve the private messages with restfb.

Connection<Conversation> pages = facebookClient.fetchConnection(profileId + 
"/conversations",Conversation.class);
```